# Accessing array elements through a coordinate array

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, vector, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize this few line of code, especially the for loop. My `x` is a `[31374230x4]` matrix, and `final.p0` is a struct containing a matrix `p0[1000x1000x500]`. The main idea is to truncate the final matrix assigning to it `x(i,4)`. I'd like to avoid the for loop,it is too slow. Any idea?

```
final.p0 = zeros(max(x(:,1)),max(x(:,2)),max(x(:,3)));
for i = 1:length(x(:,4)) 
   final.p0(x(i,1),x(i,2),x(i,3)) = x(i,4);  
end
```

Comment: Please provide a working example with a small amount of dummy data.

Comment: final.p0 = [50x50x100], and x = [1000x4].  for each iteration I want to truncate final.p0 taking the 50x50x100 values of x1,x2,x3 and assign x4 to final.p0.

Comment: by 'small amount of dummy data' they mean some actual numbers that people can copy/paste with the expected actual numbers that should be in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop can easily be avoided using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) as follows:

```
index = sub2ind(size(final.p0),x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3));
final.p0(index) = x(:,4);
```

Comment: Nice one, never used the sub2ind function. Thanx